# Android 3.1+ USB as virtual COM port

Tags: android, usb, serial-port

I have a third party usb device, that when plugged into a Windows machine, is recognized as a serial device and assigned to the COM 4 port.  I can communicate with the device just like I would with a device connected via a serial port.  For instance, I can write "abc" serially to the device via the USB connection.

I have been searching for a way to do a similar thing in Android.  If I try the Usb Host method, and use a UsbManager to open the UsbDevice, I can get one interface, with 2 endpoints.  I have tried sending control messages using the method in UsbDeviceConnection, but the method returns -1 for everything (though I don't know what I should use for the parameters of that method).

Is there a way to get an OutputStream that I can write to that will send bytes to the USB device? Right now I am looking at recompiling the kernel to include a virtual COM port driver and write some native code to be able to do this.

Thanks!

Edit: I am using the FTDI serial to USB converter circuit.  Is this compatible with Android?

Comment: could you please explain or give me a link about how you handle communicating with the device. I need to handle a scenario just like yours but I don't know how can I send data from android device to Serial port through FTDI serial to USB converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If linux kernel in your device supports FTDI, you can access this device as normal COM port. It will be named something like `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

If your kernel does not supports this type of devices, you can write your own driver using UsbHost interfaces. Check kernel's FTDI driver source code for guide.

Comment: Thanks!  I have done some further research and if you want to access it like a com port from within an Android application, you'll need root access.  A different way to do it is to write a "soft driver" inside of your Android application.  This is arguable the best way to do it if you want it to work "straight off the market."  You can issue control transfer commands via the Android USB API to set the baud rate, stop bit, etc, then use a for loop with 1 byte bulkTransfer()s.  I believe this is how [this](http://slickdevlabs.com/slick-usb-2-serial-library/) works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party drivers for this purpose,

this driver from SlickDevLabs works so nice,but cost you 100$.

http://slickdevlabs.com/slick-usb-2-serial-library/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind rooting your phone and writing some C, you can communicate with the FTDI in Android using the Android driver here:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm

There is a libftd2xx-jni.so in there that you can link with your C code - I've tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Rooting device is strongly unrecommended in common case, because i can do this for my device but i can't do this for public app, which is distributed on android market. In that case i think controlTransfer() is the only way to deal with it.